# Rails Mysql ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I created a new rails application, when i started server an tried to connect it gave this server

**error**

```
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__713349442__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Mysql is running and the password is correct. I tried connecting from command line

```
G:\simple_cms>mysql -uroot -proot simple_cms_development
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Can someone tell me what might be the possible cause for that error

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your /etc/mysql/my.cnf and check for the binding address of the mysql deamon. It probably doesnt bind to any ip. Then it will use unix sockets which are by the way faster then ip connections,...

Option name for the bind address is bind-address if theres no match it wont bind to any address. Also have a look for socket which specifies the path to the unix socket. You can use the socket like this in your database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  socket: /path/to/the/socket/mysql.sock
```

That should do it for you,

Comment: Added "socket:  E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock". did not work